# Matlab Timer function to start another function

Tags: matlab, timer, callback, handle

I want to use the timer function to execute another function, PowerOnFunc, 60 seconds after the timer has started counting.

```
%Timer Callback function
function [] = ftimer(~,~)
    while TimerHandle.TasksExecuted == 60
        PowerOnFunc();
        break;
    end
end

%Handle and execution
TimerHandle = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedrate','period',...
1,'tag','clockTimer','timerfcn',@ftimer);
start(TimerHandle);
```

However, this produces an error: 'Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-31'. Too many input arguments.' Any idea what could be causing the problem? Is there a simpler/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `timer` passes the object itself and the event to a callback function. `ftimer` must have two parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback functions in matlab automatically get two parameters **source, event** you need your callback function to support this

```
function [] = ftimer(src,evnt)
```

or more realistically, since you aren't using them just do

```
function [] = ftimer(~,~)
```

as a side note you can initialize your timer on one line

```
TimerHandle = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedrate','period', ...
1,'tag','clockTimer','timerfcn',@ftimer)
```

and another note

```
TimerHandle == 60
```

doens't work because the function doens't know what TimerHandle is. what were you trying to do with this line of code?

**EDIT**

TimerHandle == 60 is supposed to wait for 60 timeouts of the 1 second timer. It is more efficient (and probably more accurate) to set the the period to 60 seconds

```
%notice I change the time period                          v here
TimerHandle = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedrate','period',60,...
'tag','clockTimer','timerfcn',@ftimer);
```

Now the ftimer function will only get called every 60 seconds. If you wanted to look at a property of the timer from inside the callback function you have to use the source and event we talked about earlier

```
function []=ftimer(src,evnt)
    if src.TasksExecuted == 5
```

**edit2: typo in code above, now fixed**

Well, that works well. Just for your own knowledge, here are some of the fields src has:

```
Timer Object: timer-3

Timer Settings
  ExecutionMode: fixedRate
         Period: 1
       BusyMode: drop
        Running: on

Callbacks
       TimerFcn: @ftimer
       ErrorFcn: ''
       StartFcn: ''
        StopFcn: ''
```

and for more info the evnt contains:

```
K>> evnt
evnt = 
    Type: 'TimerFcn'
    Data: [1x1 struct]

K>> evnt.Data
ans = 
    time: [2015 2 19 16 37 19.3750] %this is the time the event triggered
```

Here is an alternative way to count the number of times the code has executed, or to even keep data inside of a callback function over multiple calls. Matlab has something called [persistent variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html). This is like using the word 'static' in a C function (if you know C). Otherwise it just means that the variable persists even after the function ends. Here is what your code might look like if you actually wanted to know exactly how many times it executed

```
%Timer Callback function
function [] = ftimer(src,evnt)
    %this will be saved everytime the function is called, unlike normal
    %varaibles who only 'live' as long as the function is running
    persistent times_executed;

    %initialies persisten variable
    if (isempty(times_executed))
        times_executed = 0;
    end

    fprintf('executed: %d  times\n',times_executed);

    %increments
    times_executed = times_executed +1;
end
```

Comment: Sorry-that was a bit ambiguous. I edited the code-it should actually be TimerHandle.TasksExecuted, since this value is incremented after a task is completed once every second. However, there is still the problem of this quantity not being defined until the timer function.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things jump out at me.  If you want it to execute every 60 seconds, you should set the Period.

If your timer is doing a bunch of other things, and you really do just want to call PowerOnFunc after the 60th task execution (and not at the 120th), you can access the TasksExecuted property by not tossing it out in your `ftimer` function.

```
function ftimer(th,~)
    if th.TasksExecuted == 60
        PowerOnFunc();
    end
end
```

But, if all you're looking for is the one call to `PowerOnFunc`, then I'd suggest setting `StartDelay` to 60, `TasksToExecute` to 1.  You could then just use `PowerOnFunc` as your callback, or still wrap it in `ftimer` but you wouldn't need the if statement.  This has the added benefit of stopping the timer.

Also, make sure you delete the timer at some point - clearing variables doesn't do it for you.

Comment: Kim, your method would be correct, but if you actually try it it will not work. This was the first thing I tried, and when it didn't work I opened the debugger and saw that the source (**th**) actually isn't the full timer. We can't access a number of properties from the callback, including tasksExecuted. See my solution for details

Comment: Huh... it worked for me.  I'm able to stop the timer with the debugger and access properties such as TasksExecuted, InstantPeriod, AveragePeriod (even though they don't show in the output display).

Comment: my goodness you are absolutely right. I popped open matlab again and noticed I made a typo (facepalm) in my original code. This works perfectly well. Thanks for teaching me something